# PuTTY Fatal Error Network Error

Tags: putty

I am currently trying to connect to my raspberry pi 4 model b using a Ethernet cable to my laptop. I used PuTTY to connect to the pi which at first has no issue but after a min or two it has a fatal network error and says "Network error: Software cause connection abort" then when I try to reconnect it gives me another PuTTY error which says "Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist". After that the only way for me to connect to the pi again is by restarting it by disconnecting the power and reconnecting it. Once I reconnect via putty after a min or two it goes back to the initial fatal network error. So far I have tried to Enable TCP keepalives but that doesn't work.

Comment: "connect to my raspberry pi 4 model b using a Ethernet cable to my laptop" How? What have you done? What IP address do you see? Try writing in paragraphs.